# How to comunicate two androids devices

Tags: android

I'm developing an online pong game in which two players could play between them.

I though that for it, players will have to conect to a server and it will tell the players who is online to play. Also the server will save rankings and other stuff.

But for the play, at first I though to use the server for the match too (sending coordinates, etc), but I think that is not the best design because it is really slow.

So I'm thinking that android devices have to can comunicate between them, isn't it? Any idea? They have an ID...

If they can... the server could send the ID of the opponent and with that, the match will start comunicating the stuff between the mobile devices and not with the server.

Need some help pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a direct connection between the phones, definitely. Make it so the server coordinates the matchup, sends each player the other player's data (IP and such).

You'll have to use/develop a server/client system between the players. One of the players will act as a server and the other will connect directly to it. Make sure they can properly identify each other. You can make the central server decide which player will act as the match server. A simple UDP connection over the network will do the trick.

This scheme will save you on bandwidth for the central server and probably be faster for the players. However, it IS one more subsystem you have to code.

Make sure you properly weigh those factors and remember that a fast deployment is sometimes better than no deployment at all. (SOMETIMES)

Comment: really thanks! Do you know any example or library about udp connection between mobile devices?

Comment: The SDK probably has TCP/IP and UDP libraries. Look for the networking section in any android development book and you'll find the classic server/client examples I mentioned.